# Add-Migrations EF Core in C# kernel Jupyter interacive using code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, jupyter-notebook

I can't add-migrations EF Core in Jupyter notebook C# dotnet kernel

I am using jupyter notebook for dotnet to create a database using EF Core, I just want in my realtime working to generate the migrations to use it in the same notebook

[This is what I can do to accept migrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqiqF.png)

This is what I can do to accept migrations, but I need to generate them, in this interactive environment and thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how you'd want migrations in this scenario.  Either write Entity types that map to existing tables, or create the the tables with a call to

DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

> The EnsureCreated and EnsureDeleted methods provide a lightweight
> alternative to Migrations for managing the database schema. These
> methods are useful in scenarios when the data is transient and can be
> dropped when the schema changes. For example during prototyping, in
> tests, or for local caches.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/ensure-created

Comment: Thanks much, That is what I need